# What is correct Laravel Horizon Environment Configuration To Send Bulk Email(60,000+)

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, horizon

What is the best Laravel Horizon Environment configuration to send bulk email(60,000+) on a 4GB RAM server , i tried the below but it keeps crashing my redis server when sending the emails.

```
'supervisor-email' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['bulkEmail', 'fastCron'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'processes' => 500,
            'tries' => 3,
            'minProcesses' => 1,
            'maxProcesses' => 500,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
```

with the above, 60,000+ email was queued to finish sending within 3-4hrs but My redis server keep crashing, What is the best configuration to use to avoid crashing and also make the queued job execute on time.
Thanks

Comment: Your REDIS server crashes! Does it give you any error messages?

Comment: Redis always throws error Connection refused